# Reference string resource from code

Tags: android, string, settext

I have the following string declared in strings.xml:

```
<string name="last_msg">Your last click was on</string>
```

Now when someone clicks a button, I want a textview to show this string, with a space, then a variable value that is a timestamp.

Unfortunately, using @string/last_msg isn't working, and I'm not sure how to do this properly so I'm not hardcoding in content.

Here's my code for the onClick function:

```
public void showMsgNow(View view) {
    TextView lastMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    lastMsg.setText(@string/last_msg + " " + currentTimeStamp);
}
```

I'm a newbie, any help would be great !

Comment: Search on google/web before posting questions, this is the simple thing u can even find out in docs too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer on Google:

```
getString(R.string.last_msg)
```

Comment: To clarify, this is `android.content.Context#getString`.

Answer (score 10):

you cant access `String` directly by `@`, for that you need to have context resource and then just do this...

```
lastMsg.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.last_msg) + " " + currentTimeStamp);
```

in your case use

```
<string name="last_msg">Your last click was on %1$s</string>
```

implementation:

```
public void showMsgNow(View view) {
    TextView lastMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    lastMsg.setText(context.getResources()
        .getString(R.string.last_msg, currentTimeStamp));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// getString is method of context
if (this instanceof Context) 
//If you are in Activity or Service class            
 lastMsg.setText(getString(R.string.last_msg)+ " " + currentTimeStamp);
else                         
//you need to context to get the string 
  lastMsg.setText(getString(mContext,R.string.last_msg)+ " " + currentTimeStamp);


  public String getString(Context mContext, int id){
     return mContext.getResources().getString(id);
  }
```

Comment: so i dont need to use the getString function??

Comment: when i dont use the getString function it just comes up as an integer and not the string...

Comment: No need to use here, in android R is the Resource class, all the resources stored in the raw folder have ids in the R class

Comment: String myString = lastMsg.getString().toString();

Comment: This doesn't work as R.string.last_msg is an int, you can't add a String to an int. You'll have at least to use getString(). See @Ankit's answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

use below line

```
 lastMsg.setText(getString(R.string.last_msg) + " " + currentTimeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
lastMsg.setText(R.string.last_msg + " " + new SimpleDateFormat(d-MM-YYYY).format(new Date()));
```